# How to record a screencast and embed it as video in an iWork Pages document?

Tags: macos, iwork-pages

I must do exactly that. There are rumors that PDF can have embedded video. So what I want to do is make a short screencast from a software, and then embed that into a Pages document, and export it as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while Pages can embed video in Pages documents, it won't successfully export that video to PDF. If you want to embed video in a PDF, I think you'll have to use Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

With Pages, apparently, you [cannot embed video into a PDF](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2722813?start=0&tstart=0).

However, you can embed video into an [ePub document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4168).

Under "More details on using ePub":

> Support for video embedded in a document.